# There are some problems when I use C code to control TDC (Time to Digital converter, a hardware),the problem of the "main"

Tags: c

**My problems**
I want to use C code to realize a simple function:  When I run the program, the program can control the TDC (Time to Digital converter) to start the histogram (a mode in TDC) running, then, run the histogram for the programmed time, and finally, it can stop and save the data in my computer automatically.

Unfortunately, the result is that it just saves a file full of zeros in each channel (I am sure that TDC had connected with signal perfectly because I have good data from the software the company provides).

The error I checked is that the `argc` and `argv[]` in `main()` function are not fit for the program and return error code, which the `.dll` file has set.

For hardware, are these parameters in the `main()` function like `argc` and `argv[]` in this code automatically valued? And if they are wrong, what can I do? (The hardware just only has some interfaces for signals and power).

The `.dll` file for TDC and its manual are provided.

---

**Code**

```c
int main(Sword argc, Sbyte *argv[]) {
    HRM_STATUS error;
    Uword tcspc, delay, chann;
    Uword period, clock;
    Ulong moduleCount, offset, range, i;
    HANDLE hdl[10];
    FILE *fp = nullptr;


    HRM_RefreshConnectedModuleList();
    moduleCount = HRM_GetConnectedModuleCount();
    /* If a module is present connect to the first module.
     * If no module set error and reason in last error report.
     * */
    if (moduleCount)
        HRM_GetConnectedModuleList(hdl);
    else {
        HRM_GetLastError(HRM_OPEN_USB);
        error = HRM_ERROR;
    }

    /* Initialise variables and clear error report */
    error = HRM_OK;
    tcspc = 1;          // 1 means Histogram Single-stop mode ；；；0 means MULTI-STOP mode。
    delay = 20000;      // the programmed time in ms。
    chann = 0;          // channel 0 = 0
                        // channel 1 = 0x80000
                        // channel 2 = 0x100000
                        // channel 3 = 0x180000
    period = 2000;      // clock_period


    HRM_GetLastError(HRM_OK);
    /* Set error if too few input parameters
     * and set reason in last error.
     * */
    if (argc < 4) {
        HRM_GetLastError(HRM_INV_PARAMETER);
        error = HRM_ERROR;
    }

    /* If define frequency then read period in ns and ensure
     * not greater than maximum allowable value of 2500.
     * */

    if (argc > 4)
        period = (Uword) atoi(argv[4]);
    if (period > 2500)
        period = 2500;

    /* Read from ~20ns before 1/2 cycle to ~20ns after.
     * Form the offset in the memory where reading is to start.
     * This is ~ 20ns before half period of clock. Then set the
     * range for reading results of 40ns.
     * */
    clock = (Uword)(period / 2);
    i = (Ulong) clock;
    if (i >= 20)
        i = (Ulong)(i - 20);
    offset = (Ulong)(i * 1000 / 27);
    range = (Ulong)(40 * 1000 / 27);

    /* Form the programmable clock value. Upper byte and lower byte
     * are set to 1/2 period in 5ns per bit - 1.
     * */

    clock = (Uword)(clock / 5);
    if (clock)
        clock--;
    clock = (Uword)((clock << 8) | clock);

    /* 1. Set the flag for TCSPC or MULTI-SCALAR mode
     * 2. Read in the time in ms for running the histogram.
     * 3. Form the 4 channel edge enables based on the input parameter.
     * */
    if (error == HRM_OK) {
        tcspc = (Uword)(argv[1][0] & 1);
        delay = (Sword) atoi(argv[3]);
        if (argv[2][0] == '1')
            chann |= 0x9000;
        if (argv[2][1] == '1')
            chann |= 0x0900;
        if (argv[2][2] == '1')
            chann |= 0x0090;
        if (argv[2][3] == '1')
            chann |= 0x0009;
    }

    /* Set the clock frequency. */
    if (error == HRM_OK)
        error = HRM_SetFrequencySelectionRegister(hdl[0], clock);

    /* Set the channel edge enables. */
    if (error == HRM_OK)
        error = HRM_SetEdgeSensitivityRegister(hdl[0], chann);

    /* Clear the memory. */
    if (error == HRM_OK)
        error = HRM_InitMemory(hdl[0], 0, 0x200000, 0);

    /* Start the histogram running. */
    if (error == HRM_OK) {
        /* the third parameters  0=27ps, 1=54ps, 2=108ps */
        error = HRM_StartHistogramFSM(hdl[0], tcspc, 0);
    }

    /* Run the histogram for the programmed time in ms. */
    if (error == HRM_OK)
        for (i = GetTickCount(); (Uword)(GetTickCount() - i) < delay;);

    /* Stop the histogram process. */
    if (error == HRM_OK)
        error = HRM_SetModeBitsRegister(hdl[0], 0x0030);

    /* Read all the memory into the buffer. */
    if (error == HRM_OK)
        error = HRM_ReadMemory(hdl[0], 0x0030, chann, 0x200000,
                               buffer);     //byte数据类型的buffer

    /* Open the file and set the headings. */
    if (error == HRM_OK) {
        fopen_s(&fp, "HISTOGRAM.txt", "w + t");
        fprintf(fp, " Chan 2, Chan 3\n");
    }

    /* For each channel read all the time-bins from 20ns before to 20ns
     * after the 1/2 clock cycle and save then in the file.
     * */

    for (i = 0; i != range && error == HRM_OK; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, " % ld, % ld, % ld, % ld\n",
                buffer[i + CH0_ADDR + offset], buffer[i + CH1_ADDR + offset],
                buffer[i + CH2_ADDR + offset], buffer[i + CH3_ADDR + offset]);
    }

    /* Close the file and print error code if failed. */
    if (fp)
        fclose(fp);
    if (error == HRM_OK)
        printf("Done");
    else {
        error = HRM_GetLastError(HRM_OK);
        printf("Failed: Error code = % d", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program is running on some hardware/embedded system? Does that system provide an OS, or is this a standalone program? If any arguments are passed to main in a standalone program depends on the runtime environment. You need to consult the manual of your runtime environment to find out if/how you can configure them.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I'm sorry that I miss the header file in my questions.  The header file contains a special file named **HRMTimeAPI.h**,and there are also some other **.dll** files. These files were provided by the hardware company to control the TDC. And I have checked the code by running the code line by line, at the same time,I pay attention to the error value(0 means success,1 means fail). Finally, I found that a piece of judgement statement  about **"argc"**  returns an error. But this parameter was defined in "int main(.... argc,....argv[]) ",Should I give it a value by myself?

Comment: Do you run your program on a PC, or is this something that runs on a microcontroller? As you mention .dll files, I suspect we are talking about a hosted (i.e. PC) scenario, where there is an operating system. In such a case, these values are given to your program as (command-line) arguments. How do you invoke your program?

Comment: argc should never be set by hand.

Comment: There is no OS. But the company provided a software to control the TDC(The TDC is a black box ,and there are nothing but some interfaces for signal and power) . For experiment convenience, I have to use a piece of code to control it. And its manual claims that it can only be programmed by C,and offers some example.As you can see , the example returns error..... //emoji cry.... I just learn few about C language. Looking forward your help!

Comment: I run the code on PC.

Comment: "Looking forward your help!" Have you tried actually handling the errors as suggested in the answer?

Comment: I don't know where the **"argc"** 's value comes from. The TDC(Time to digital converter)  is connected with PC by a USB cable. And the TDC will processes the signal to data, and send it to computer for data fitting. And the PC set some parameters such as "start" 、“stop ”、“channel select“ to the TDC。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I note is that you have no return statements, even after error checking (which is great!). If those errors are severe enough as to interpret that the code shouldn't run when encountered, then you should `return 1` (or any number you like - you could use a different return number for each error if you wish).

At the end of the `main()` function, if everything went alright, `return 0`.

As I said, I strongly suspect that there may be errors somewhere, which although being checked, they are not *handled*.

Also, that main is huuuge, try to split it up a bit making dedicated functions for each part, so that each function has its own responsibility, and try checking each part individually. Can you debug it? At least adding some prints? (Ideally, you should debug with a dedicated debugger, but as an emergency exit, prints are better than nothing!)

Comment: Thank you for your help !!!  Paying attention to the error value does a good way to checking the code. And I have run and checked the code  line by line.  I have tried to check each part individually.. There are no error except the **argc** line. . Because there are no signal light on TDC,I don't know whether it has stoppd or started by my code.But the code does output a flie, which full of zero.(not what I want)

Comment: Thank you very much ,and for really, I am not good at C language. //emoji handshake